# Crear un pagination en wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, funciones

en mi wordpress he creado un menu en el Backand que se llama "Opiniones". Este lo he puesto como loop en mi pagina, de tal forma que muestre los ultimos 10 post.

```
<div class="container">
    <?php
        $categories = get_categories( array(
            'child_of'=>'Opiniones'
        ) );

        $subcategories = array();

        foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
            $subcategories[] = $category->cat_ID;
        }
    ?>

    <?php
        $new_loop = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'Opiniones',
        'category__in' => $subcategories,
        'posts_per_page' => 10
        ) );
    ?>

    <?php if ( $new_loop->have_posts() ) : while ( $new_loop->have_posts() ) : $new_loop->the_post(); ?>




    <div>

        <hr/>

            <div class="info">
                <div class="autor"><p><?php the_field('autor-title'); ?></p>&nbsp;<strong><p><?php the_field('autor'); ?></p></strong></div>
                <div class="datum"><p><?php the_field('datum_title'); ?></p>&nbsp;<strong><p><?php the_field('datum'); ?></p></strong></div>

            </div>

            <h2><?php the_title(''); ?></h2>


            <?php the_content(''); ?>



    </div>



    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

    </div>
```

Ahora lo que necesito es crear un Pagination debajo de tal forma que el visitante puea ir hacia atras y ver los post anteriores pero solo del menu "Opiniones". Soy bastante nuevo en esto y aun hay cosas que se me escapan.
Gracias a todos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para paginaciones en wordpress yo uso un loop estandar:

```
<?php query_posts( array( 'category_name' => categorias, 'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ) ); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <!-- Aquí va el contenido HTML --> 


<?php endwhile; ?> 
        <?php posts_nav_link(); ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Te dejo la documentación de paginación:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Adding_the_.22Paged.22_Parameter_to_a_Query